# Foreign Key Constraint Error - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a database containing information from a game for an assignment but am having issues when creating the tables with assigning the primary and foreign keys. Any help would be amazing.

The error code I am getting is: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint on table Boss. It creates the first table fine it just stops working and throws the error at the foreign key when creating table boss.

Within the item table the field Boss needs to be able have the same data entered for multiple different items.

```
CREATE TABLE item ( ID SERIAL, Name VARCHAR(35), Boss VARCHAR(25), Type VARCHAR(20), Slot VARCHAR(20),  PRIMARY KEY (Name,Boss) );
CREATE TABLE boss ( ID SERIAL, Boss VARCHAR(25), Type VARCHAR(20), Location VARCHAR(20), Difficulty INT, PRIMARY KEY (ID, Location), FOREIGN KEY (Boss) REFERENCES item(Boss) );
CREATE TABLE dungeon ( ID SERIAL, Name VARCHAR(25), Location VARCHAR(20), Rating INT, PRIMARY KEY (Name), FOREIGN KEY (Location) REFERENCES boss(Location) );
```

Comment: mysql or sql server? There are not the same thing. And what do you mean by "trouble"? I assume that means you are getting an error message. Sharing that message would go a long way to others helping.

Comment: I am using XAMPP and phpmyadmin to create it. When I try and execture the code above I get the error:

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: I strongly recommend the relation of tables by numeric primary key whenever possible. Have you tried wrapping your statements in:
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: By wrapping I assume you mean putting the check 0 ahead of my code and check 1 after?

Comment: I managed to create the tables without any Primary keys or Foreign keys and using the command ALTER TABLE added Primary Keys to ID for each table however when I try and add a foreign key I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

I can see many things wrong with your db creation script, but I will only stick to the ones that immediately affect getting it to work in the first place:

1. You should always refer to another table through its primary key and nothing else.
2. Your references are put in the wrong tables. If you want to refer to a "boss" from "item" then you should do just that and not refer to "item" from "boss".
3. But the most important thing is that references should be of the same type as the primary keys they refer to.
4. A composite key is a bad idea when you don't really need one.

So, a working script would be:

```
CREATE TABLE dungeon ( ID BIGINT(20), Name VARCHAR(25), Location VARCHAR(20), Rating INT, PRIMARY KEY (ID) );

CREATE TABLE boss ( ID BIGINT(20), Type VARCHAR(20), LocationId BIGINT(20), Difficulty INT, PRIMARY KEY (ID), FOREIGN KEY (LocationId) REFERENCES dungeon (ID) );

CREATE TABLE item ( ID BIGINT(20), Name VARCHAR(35), BossId BIGINT(20), Type VARCHAR(20), Slot VARCHAR(20),  PRIMARY KEY (ID), FOREIGN KEY (BossId) REFERENCES boss (ID) );
```

You can adjust it to your needs, but before doing that, I would suggest reading a good book on database design or -at least- a tutorial on basic relational databases principles.

Comment: Thank you for your help I am reading as much as I can but am really new to this as a whole. Your code works which is defiantly a step forward from what I had however some of the fields are different data types to what I would need to enter into them. My question is how would I work around this? One example being the LocationID which would need to be text as its a written location not a number.